# Passing Custom Form parameter to formset

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have the following Form defined

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):  
    def __init__(self, readOnly=False, *args, **kwargs):  
      super(MyForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwrds)  
      if readOnly:  
        Do stuff to make the inputs readonly
```

MyForm works perfectly when I instantiate it in the view as a form
`form = MyForm(readOnly=True, instance=ModelA)`

but when I try to use it in the inlineformset_factory
`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm(readOnly=True))`
I get the error  "NoneType object is not callable."

I think this is because the form is being initialised without a model instance
because MyForm is being initialised within the inline

I know the problem is the way I am using the MyForm in the inline call
because I get the same error if I do either of the following

`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm(readOnly=True))`
`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm())`

but it works if I do
`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm)`

obviously the readOnly param defaults to False and my inputs are not changed.
Does anyone know how I can pass the readOnly param to MyForm using the inlineformset_factory or how else I can achieve what I want?

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Digging through `django.forms.models` you can see that `inlineformset_factory` needs a form *class*, not an instance.  This is why your last try works and the other fail...passing in an instance won't work.

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
class MyReadOnlyForm(MyForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyReadOnlyForm,self).__init__(readOnly=True, *args,**kwargs)


Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyReadOnlyForm)
```

If you need both versions

```
if read_only is True:
    form_class = MyReadOnlyForm
else:
    form_class = MyForm 

Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=form_class)
```

Comment: That will force me to always have readOnly as True, my bad for the way iI wrote the code above. I would like the readOnly value to be either True or False and th form to work accordingly.

`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm(readOnly=readONlyValue))'

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I did find the following in another post and was wondering if one was better than the other.

`Formset = inlineformset_factory(ModelA, ModelB form=MyForm)`
`Formset.form = staticmethod(curry(MyForm, reaOnly=readOnlyvalue))`
`myFormset = Formset(request.Files, instance=modelAInst)`