# Django: inlineformset_factory, passing parameters/variables

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am fairly new with django and I am having a problem and would like to request some assistance.

I am getting an error with passing my custom param to my form that says

```
KeyError at /someurl
'my_arg'

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
    Django Version: 1.8.2
    Exception Type: KeyError
    Exception Value: 'my_arg'
    Exception Location: ..../forms.py in __init__, line 108(points at 'my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')' line)
    Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
    Python Version: 2.7.10
    Python Path:    
    ['C:\\Users\\lolwat\\Desktop\\ITSWEBSITE',
     'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
     'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
     'C:\\Python27',
     'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

It also say this at the error page:

```
Error during template rendering
    ...
    {% for field in form %}
    ...
```

This is my form:

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.my_arg = kwargs.pop("my_arg")
    super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SomeForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg')
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And my views:

```
myformset = inlineformset_factory(modelA, modelB, formset = BaseFormSet, form=SomeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)

def someview(request, obj_id):
    var1 = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, id = obj_id)
    somevalue = var1.ModelFieldValue
    form = myformset (request.POST, my_arg=somevalue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = myformset(instance = myinstance, my_arg=somevalue)

     return render(....)
```

What I am doing wrong or am I doing it right? Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

I tried using `myformset.form = staticmethod(curry(SomeForm, my_arg=somevalue))`

And my views look like this:

```
from django.utils.functional import curry

myformset = inlineformset_factory(modelA, modelB, formset = BaseFormSet, form=SomeForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)

def someview(request, obj_id):
    var1 = get_object_or_404(SomeModel, id = obj_id)
    somevalue = var1.ModelFieldValue
    myformset.form = staticmethod(curry(SomeForm, my_arg=somevalue))
    form = myformset (request.POST, my_arg=somevalue)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
    else:
        form = myformset(instance = myinstance, my_arg=somevalue)

     return render(....)
```

And It's working, I am using the `my_arg` to filter the SomeForm's `ModelChoiceField` queryset via `__init__` and my form looks like this:

```
class SomeForm(ModelForm):
   MyField = ModelChoiceField(queryset=SomeModel.objects.none())
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop('my_arg', None)
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['MyField'].queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(fkey = my_arg)
```

And upon save I get `<DjangoObject> is not JSON serializable` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because your inner form `SomeForm` does not receive `my_arg` as a parameter in `kwargs`. And because you use `kwargs.pop('my_arg')` without a default value -> you get a `KeyError`. If you use `.pop` with a default value provided (`kwargs.pop('my_arg', None)`) you wont get a `KeyError`.

If you really need to pass `my_arg` to your inner `SomeForm` take a look at this questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442040/pre-populate-an-inline-formset), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314350/passing-initial-into-djangos-modelformset) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610892/passing-custom-form-parameter-to-formset)

**UPDATE:**

As far as I can see, you need `my_arg` to filter queryset of a field. Well you don't need to this at `inner_form.__init__`, but after constructing all forms inside your `formset.__init__` method.

Something like this:

```
class BaseFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_arg = kwargs.pop("my_arg")
        super(BaseFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.fields['my_field'].queryset = SomeModel.objects.filter(fkey = my_arg)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I tried using `myformset.form = staticmethod(curry(SomeForm, my_arg=somevalue))` and now I am getting an error: `<DjangoObject> is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Just by the error I don't think I can help you. I personally never needed to send additional parameter to an inner form, so I'm not quite sure whats the best approach to do it. When I have time I will try it myself and post you and update, until then - keep reading :)

Comment: I'll post another question because I tested it and this is another matter entirely, good read tho, thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: I'm getting a `[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` error with that

Comment: Yes, it's in my template, what causes it I think is the for loop in the `BaseFormSet` as it is `Tampered with`, anyway what I did works though